# Rotational Motion Equation Problem

Tags: kinematics

So I was told that a=v^2/r for acceleration of an object moving in a circular path.
However when also given the equations a=αr and v=ωr,

Thus:

αr=v^2/r

αr=(ωr)^2/r

αr=ω^2r

**α=ω^2**

But obviously the above conclusion should be wrong, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an object moving in a circle (or any curve, but the circle is a simple example) the acceleration has two components: radial and tangential. For motion in a circle the radial acceleration is given by:

$$ a_r = r\omega^2 = \frac{v^2}{r} $$

and the tangential acceleration is given by:

$$ a_t = r\alpha $$

In your first equation you have equated $a_t$ on the left side to $a_r$ on the right side. The problem is that the radial and tangential accelerations are independent quantities and are generally not the same. For example an object moving at constant speed in a circle has a non-zero radial acceleration but a zero tangential acceleration.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know the difference between radial and tangential acceleration until now.